# website not upload using webview

Tags: iphone

ihave write the following code 
but it does nothing in consloe it shows Unknown scheme, doing nothing

```
[webview setDeleagte self];
[webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:sourcelinkStr]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *strURL = @"https://facebook.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
webView.delegate = self;
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

now , 
    we have to define Methods For LoadRequest
thanks..